# How to insert form array values into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm stuck, I want to insert form data from array fields like below into MySQL:

```
<input type='text' name='name[]' />` and `<input type='text' name='url[]' />
```

I know how to output the data for one field like this example

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
{
  echo $name;
}
```

But in my form I have both `<input type='text' name='name[]' />` and `<input type='text' name='url[]' />` how can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: foreach($_POST['url'] as $url){

echo $url;

}

Comment: Please include your table schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try and avoid querying the DB over and over and just put everything in one big insert statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, url) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST['name'] as $i => $name) 
{ 
  // Get values from post.
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'][$i]);

  // Add to database
  $query = $query." ('$name','$url') ,";
}
$query = substr($query,0,-1); //remove last char
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

That way you only have to hit the database once, making the insert much faster.
An other benefit is that **if** the engine supports transactions (InnoDB et al) all inserts happen in a single transaction.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the indexer of your loop like so:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $i => $name) 
{ 
  // Get values from post.
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'][$i]);

  // Add to database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `url`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$url."')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Of course, it's a good practice to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the values before adding them in your query.

Answer (score -3):

You need to implode your arrays if you want to store all of the values in a single DB field.

```
$all_names= implode(",", $name[]);
```

This will put all of your array values in to a single variable, comma separated.

Comment: -1, storing CSV values in a database as a very bad idea for lots of reasons.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for some reading materials? I see this done pretty regularly, I'd like to learn why it's bad and a better way to store values like a checkbox array.