# only last row of the html table gets inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql

> bill.php

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Bill Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bill.css">
  </head>
   <body onload="start()">
         <script src="bill.js"></script>
         <form name='adminform' method='post' action="billdb.php" onload="return start()">
        <input type="text" style="position: absolute;top:100px;" value="<?php echo $tnumber ?>">           
        <div id="date"></div>
        <div id="clock"></div>
      <label id="billno">Bill No:</label>
        <label id="items">Items</label>
        <label id="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <label id="price">Price</label>
        <label id="amount">Amount</label>
        <label id="tax">Service Tax</label>
        <label id="total">Total</label>

         <?php 
         while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
        {
        //   $title=$row['title'];
      echo "<table style>";
            echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td id='td1'>" .$row['subtitle'] ;
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='subtitle'  value= '{$row['subtitle']}'>";  
     echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";
     echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";
     echo $row['quantity'] ;
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity'  value= '{$row['quantity']}'>";  
     echo $row['price'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='price'  value= '{$row['price']}'>";  
$amount=$row['price'] * $row['quantity'];
echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp"; echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp"; echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";
echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp"; echo "&nbsp";echo "&nbsp";
  echo "$amount.0000</td>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount'  value= '{$amount}'>";  
  $total=$total+$amount;
  $total1=$total+50.000;

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='total'  value= '{$total}'>"; 
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='tax'  value= '{50.0000}'>";  
     }
       echo "</table>";
     $billno=$row4['last_bill'];
          ?>
         <div id="bd"><?php echo $billno ?></div>    
         <input type="hidden" name="billno" value="<?php echo $billno?>">
         <div id="tamt"><?php echo "$total1.0000"?></div>
         <div id="taxamt"> 50.0000</div>
         <input type="text" name="custno" value="<?php echo $cusno?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="tnumber" value="<?php echo $tnumber?>">
         <input type="submit" id="generate" name="generate" value="Generate Bill">
        </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

> billdb.php

```
   require_once('conn.php');
   $billno=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'billno'));
   $custno=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'custno'));
   $tnumber=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'tnumber'));
   $subtitle=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'subtitle'));
   $quantity=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'quantity'));
   $price=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'price'));
   $amount=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'amount'));
   $tax=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'tax'));
   $total=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'total'));
   $sql="insert into  billmgmt(billno,custno,tnumber,subtitle,quantity,price,amount,tax,total)values('$billno','$c ustno','$tnumber','$subtitle','$quantity','$price','$amount','$tax','$total')" or          die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
      $res=  mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
      echo "success";
     mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

> I have retrieved the contents from mysql database into html table,From html table i need to store the values in a billmgmt table.but the last row values of html table alone gets stored,with this code.Please help me out .........

Comment: you got this echo "success"; ??

Comment: yes but values not inserting

Comment: you have no error in mysqli ? you set displaying errors on ?

Comment: `'$c ustno'` is the space a typo? Give a `echo mysqli_error($dbhandle);` after the query execution. It will show you the reason if failing.

Comment: @echo_Me i gave that since it didnt insert atleast it ll tell the error.

Comment: you verfified if its `$custno` and not `$c ustno` in your insert query?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger  sorry the table was not inside sample database,but with this code only last row of the table gets inserted into the table

Comment: @user3516005 In your form, you will have to use input arrays if you are sending in several fields with same name. Check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320512/how-to-insert-form-array-values-into-mysql)** post.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger can u please give example of one data in my code?

Comment: can you try this `echo "<input type='hidden' name='subtitle'  value= '".$row['subtitle']."'>";` instead of yours ? and see if its inserted to tdatabase

Comment: @echo_Me now im able  to insert please the edited post

Comment: @user3516005 Can you confirm if the last value that you said gets stored in database, are they correct values? Because I do not see `$cusno` and `$tnumber` being stored anywhere.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger those two values are the session value i have displayed inside textbox

Comment: how you fetching `$res2` and there is no query ??

Comment: its in another php file where i have the select query to fetch the details

Comment: you mean just total get inserted ?

Comment: how you are getting this value `row4['last_bill']` ?

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of yours.

```
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='subtitle'  value= '".$row['subtitle']."'>";


   echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity'  value= '".$row['quantity']."'>";
```

and same for other inputs , just change them like that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your HTML inputs to arrays by giving `[]` next to their name as:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='subtitle[]'  value= '{$row['subtitle']}'>";
                                        #^here
```

This should be **for all your inputs that are repeated multiple times in your form**.

And then in your PHP, you need to loop through them:

```
$post = $_POST;

//single values
$billno=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['billno']); 
$custno=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['custno']); 
$tnumber=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['tnumber']); 

//multiple values go in loop
foreach($post['subtitle'] as $key=>$val) 
{ 
$subtitle=$val; 
$quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['quantity'][$key]); 
$price=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['price'][$key]); 
$amount=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['amount'][$key]); 
$tax=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['tax'][$key]); 
$total=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle,$post['total'][$key]); 

//insert statement combined with single and multiple values
$sql="insert into billmgmt(billno,custno,tnumber,subtitle,quantity,price,amount,tax,total)values('$billno','$custno','$tnumber','$subtitle','$quantity','$price','$amount','$tax','$total')" or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle)); 
//added this line so you can know what's being entered, comment later
echo $sql; 
$res= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql); 
} 


echo mysqli_error($dbhandle); 
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

Also, the curly braces `{}` need to be removed from here since it's static value:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='tax'  value= '{50.0000}'>";  #remove {}
```

Comment: @I can Has Cheezwburger Notice: Undefined variable: post in D:\server\htdocs\samproject\billdb.php on line 23

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\server\htdocs\samproject\billdb.php on line 23 this is what the error im getting

Comment: @user3516005 Can you do a `print_r($post);` before the `foreach` and see if it outputs anything? Oh it seems I missed closing a circle bracket `)` at that line. Please amend as `foreach($post['subtitle'] as $key=>$val){`

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\server\htdocs\samproject\billdb.php on line 24

Comment: @user3516005 Please try the `print_r($post);` before the `foreach()`

Comment: @I can Has Cheezburger whenever i use $_POSt in netbeans it says do not access super global array directly,thats why i use fileter_input in my code always

Comment: @I can Has Cheezburger  i tried  even this print_r($post);

Comment: @user3516005 Haven't tried netbeans, but looking around it seems like it's only a hint. You can disable it for the time being since we are debugging. And I asked you to do the `print_r($post);` to see what's stored inside the array.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger Array ( [subtitle] => [quantity] => [price] => [amount] => [total] => [tax] => [billno] => 95 [custno] => 85 [tnumber] => toep1003 [generate] => Generate Bill ) 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\server\htdocs\samproject\billdb.php on line 28

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51050/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-user3516005)

Comment: @I can Has Cheezburger can u pl update the answer u gave because that only works correctly