# only can insertes last row data of table into session

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code

```
                <?php
                    $count = 1;
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `scheduledata`
                    WHERE `departdate` = '$departdatephp'
                    AND   `orginplace_id` = '$orginplacephp'
                    AND   `desplace_id`   = '$desplacephp' ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                         ?>


                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $count;?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $row["departtime"];?><input type="hidden" name="departtime" value="<?php echo $row['departtime'];?>" method="post"></th>
                            <th><?php echo $row["returntime"];?><input type="hidden" name="returntime" value="<?php echo $row['returntime'];?>" method="post"></th>
                            <th><?php echo $row["adultprice"]; ?>MYR<input type="hidden" name="adultprice" value="<?php echo $row['adultprice'];?>" method="post"></th>
                            <th><?php echo $row['schedule_id'];?><input type="hidden" name="scheduleid" value="<?php echo $row['schedule_id'];?>" method="post"></th>
                            <th><?php echo $row['flight_id'];?><input type="hidden" name="flightid" value="<?php echo $row['flight_id'];?>" method="post"></th>
                            <th><button type="submit" class="submit-button" method="post" name="departbtn[]">booking</button></th>
                            <?php
                                $count = $count+1;}
                             ?>
                        </tr>
```

Lest says i had 3 choice of booking like this
[3 booking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smYsC.png)

Here is my output code

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['departbtn']))
  {
$departtimephp = $_POST['departtime'];
$returntimephp   = $_POST['returntime'];
$price = $_POST['adultprice'];
$scheduleid   = $_POST['scheduleid'];
$flightid   = $_POST['flightid'];

$_SESSION['departtime'] = $departtimephp ;
$_SESSION['returntime'] = $returntimephp ;
$_SESSION['adultprice']   =   $price ;
$_SESSION['scheduleid']   = $scheduleid ;
$_SESSION['flightid']= $flightid  ;

print_r($_SESSION['departtime']);
print_r($_SESSION['returntime']);
print_r($_SESSION['adultprice']);
print_r($_SESSION['scheduleid']);
print_r($_SESSION['flightid']);
 }
  ?>
```

No matter which choice I select, the out put is always the last row of table, I guess its because there all had same variable name so system direct insert last row data.
My problem is a bit same like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181078/only-last-row-of-the-html-table-gets-inserted-into-database/23181420#23181420), they suggest using array[] to solve this but I got error when i add a foreach inside a isset, so any idea how to get the correct data?
Appreciate for any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown doesn't explicitly show this, but I strongly suspect that *the entire table* is your `form`.  Which means that no matter which button you click, *all* values are being submitted.

For starters, the browser wouldn't know which one you "meant" and any given value would just overwrite the previous one in the form POST.  (Which explains the behavior you're seeing... you always get the last record.)  But, aside from that... Why?  Why submit *all of the data* when you really just need a single identifier of the record which was selected?

For each row in the table, put an entire self-contained `form`.  Something like this:

```
<tr>
    <!--- your other table cells --->
    <th>
        <form method="post" action="someAction.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="flightid" value="<?php echo $row['flight_id'];?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="submit-button" method="post" name="departbtn">booking</button>
        </form>
    </th>
</tr>
```

(You can put more of those `hidden` form fields there, as many as you like really.  Though honestly you should just need an identifier.  The server already has the rest of the data.  And the more fields you use is just more opportunities for users to mess with the system.)

That way when you click a button, there's no ambiguity on the option being selected.  Each form is entirely self-contained and has only the data it needs to post.

Comment: Yeah, u are correct. the entire table is a <form>. Thanks for help. After i switch the <form> inside <tr> its work perfectly now ! But i don really get it , it's because the <form> include $sql = select ... , so I will always get the last record?

Comment: @CheeSengTeo: The form doesn't include any server-side code.  It's just that when the form puts together all of the POST values client-side, it needs to construct key/value pairs for the data.  So if a bunch of rows are using the same keys, only the last row is going to be used.  It's analogous to setting the same variable over and over in a loop.  After the loop, only the last value will remain.

Comment: I see..., and about your comment : (Though honestly you should just need an identifier). You mean it's a bad way to get data like this right? I really no idea about identifier. If possible could u give me some example or some link about identifier ?

Comment: @CheeSengTeo: Well, it's really just a question of what information the server *needs* in order to complete the given task. Everything that you're outputting from `scheduledata` is information you already have. All you really need from the client-side is which record was picked. You don't need all the information that's already in the record, you just need a single identifier (primary key) for the record. Don't let the users tell you the schedule data, just which schedule record they want.